# How can I update simple object values in Firestore based on matching name values?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

this is my first post and I'm hoping someone can help me out :)
My react app tracks people signing in for work and signing out. The form inputs go to my firestore database collection and get saved as objects with values.

on the SignOut component I want to search my database for the entry matching the inputs "firstName", "lastName", and today's date. Then I want to add on the new sign out timestamp and 2 other values.
How can I update simple object values in Firestore based on matching name values?

I think my code is getting stuck at my filter in "matchedEntrys" because console.log shows nothing.
Thank you so much for any help, I really need developer friends lol

Here's my code sample (the newSignOut object holds the values from the form inputs):

```
function SignOut(props) {
    const { firebase } = React.useContext(FirebaseContext);
    const [filteredEntrys, setFilteredEntrys] = React.useState([]);
    const [entrys, setEntrys] = React.useState([]);
    const { handleSubmit, handleChange, values } = useFormValidation(
        INITIAL_STATE,
        validateForm,
        handleCreateLink
    );

    function handleCreateLink() {
        const { id, jobNumber, isSigningIn, date, timeOut, firstName, lastName, injury, breaks } = values;
        const getDate = new Date();
        const queryFirstName = firstName.toLowerCase();
        const queryLastName = lastName.toLowerCase();
        const newSignOut = {
            id,
            jobNumber,
            isSigningIn,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            timeOut: moment(getDate).format('h:mm a'),
            date: moment(getDate).format('L'),
            injury,
            breaks
        }
        console.log(queryFirstName);
        firebase.db
        .collection('log')
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            const entrys = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                return { date: doc.date, ...doc.data() }
            })
            setEntrys(entrys)
            console.log(entrys)
        })
        const matchedEntrys = entrys.filter(entry => {
            return (
            entry.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(queryFirstName) &&
            entry.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(queryLastName) &&
            entry.date.includes(moment(getDate).format('L'))
            );
        });
        setFilteredEntrys(matchedEntrys);
        console.log(filteredEntrys);
        props.history.push('/success');
    }
```

Comment: ```console.log(entrys)``` is working? try to move the code after ```.then``` within  the last callback after ```console.log(entrys)```